# Long execution time using position

Tags: list-manipulation, timing

I have two lists, for example:

```
 List1={2,4,6,8,10,12}
 List2={4,10,12}
```

I want to find the positions in List1 such that the element at that position is equal to the element in List2. I can do this using Position and Do:

```
 Do[po[k] = Position[List1, x_ /; x == List2[[k]]], {k, 1, Length[List2]}]
```

I actually have a much longer list, and the position operation takes 176 seconds. Is there a different way that allows me to reduce the execution time?

EDIT 1:

If list1 depends on some parameters p1 and p2, for example I have List1[p1,p2], how can I have a table of position for every parameter in a given range? I always think to a Do Loop, and I wonder if there is something more efficient.

Comment: `Position[List1, #] & /@ List2`

Comment: Does it fit your needs `Lookup[PositionIndex@List1, List2]`?

Comment: @cvgmt it gives me a blank list with my real list, now I edit my question with some real number from my list.

Comment: @cvgmt I solved thank you!

Comment: @Kuba it gives me some error messages

Comment: @Orion not for the case you've presented.

Comment: @Kuba No for List1 and List2 it has a very good timing but now I'm trying with my real lists. It says Missing["KeyAbsent", ...]

Comment: @Orion Try: `Lookup[PositionIndex @ List1, Key /@ List2]`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit It always gives me Missing["KeyAbsent", ...] error :/

Comment: @Orion Is `List1` deeper than one level? `PositionIndex` only collects elements at the first level.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit No, it is one level

Comment: In that case you're just going to have to give us a sample of the list you're working with (using, e.g., `RandomSample[..., 20]` or something) and update the question to show the problem.